# Escaping a string with Blade, rendering HTML

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a `$text` variable that holds some text and HTML code. I would like to render its HTML, but still make sure the rest of the string is escaped.

```
$text = 'Example text with image <img src"image_1.jpg">. More text...'

// This will render the HTML but will NOT escape the string
{!! $text !!}

// This will escape and display the variable as raw string, with no HTML rendering
{{ $text }}
```

In Laravel 5, is there a way to escape a string with Blade while allowing HTML?

Comment: what do you mean by "escaping"?

Comment: I mean the protection against XSS that's normally achieved with double curly brackets in Blade - `{{...}}`. It seems I can have only one of two at the same time: an escaped string with no HTML rendering OR rendering with no escaping...

Comment: How should the application decide if it has to escape an HTML tag or not? The very purpose of escaping is to *not* render HTML.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I get that. Just wondering whether there is a way in Blade to specify such behaviour - e.g. by specifying allowed chars etc. So the only way I can achieve this is with native PHP? I also remember there was a `e()` function that Blade uses under the hood. Could it be useful?

Comment: @lukasgeiter you're not quite right. There can be allowed tags in escaped HTML, like ``div``, ``p``, ``b``, ``td``, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such functionality in blade. You can not just allow specific HTML tags, because they may have unwanted stuff (like onload) inside them. Processing of string may be tricky. Have you considered **markup language**?

Comment: Exactly! +1 for the mention of `onload`

Comment: I second that. Use a meta language with a specific set of allowed elements like markdown _if_ you display user generated contents. If not (like in your example) just display it unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to do some manual processing of the string.

It might be possible that Purifier https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier will do what you need. It will make strings harmless and then it is safe to print the html in it.

Otherwise you need to write your own parser if nothing else like that is found.